# Composition API watch handler

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How do I refactor this:

```
watch: {
    count: {
      handler (v) {
        if (v) this.intervalId = setInterval(() => { this.now++ }, 1000)
        else clearInterval(this.intervalId)
      },
      immediate: true
    }
  }
```

Into Composition API?

I tried something like that, which throws errors:

```
watch(()=> {
      count.value,
      handler (value) {
      if (value)
        intervalId.value = setInterval(() => {
          now.value++;
        }, 1000);
      else clearInterval(intervalId.value);
      },
      immediate: true
      })
```

Comment: By replacing `watch` option with `watch` function, and replacing other options with respective composition functions. If you have specific problems with this, consider updating the question. Just asking to write the code for you isn't a proper SO question (not a question at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor it as below. You can pass `immediate` option to the `watch` method as the 3rd parameter in `Vue 3`

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const count = Vue.ref(0);
    const now = Vue.ref(0);
    const intervalId = Vue.ref(0);

    Vue.watch(count, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
      if (currentValue) intervalId.value = setInterval(() => now.value++, 1000);
    }, {
      immediate: true
    });
    
    Vue.onUnmounted(() => { clearInterval(intervalId.value) });

    return {
      count,
      now
    };
  }
}).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ count }} - {{ now }}
  <button @click="count++">Increment</button>
  <button @click="count=0">reset</button>
</div>
```

###### Reference:

- [Composition API - Lifecycle hooks](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks)

**P.S:** You can use `import {watch, ref, onUnmounted} from "vue"` to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. 
I didn't mention it in the question but 'clearInterval' is mentioned after the watch as  `onUnmounted(() => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    });`
so how do I call it properly? (sorry for the mess)

Comment: hold on, let me update my answer.

Comment: haha sure, thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer to include the `onUnmounted` hook.

Comment: mmm apparentay now the lack of `else` is stopping the functionality.. I think I still need to call `clearInterval` from within else

Comment: Well if you require the else, then you can simple check for a `false` condition like `if(!count.value) clearInterval(intervalId.value);` in your `onUnmounted` hook